# How to Intelligently add line breaks to large blocks of text with Javascript or Ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby

I am looking for a library or algorithm that can take my long block of text that has no line breaks and split it into paragraphs that mostly make sense to human readability.

Ex.

```
I am looking for a library or algorithm that can take my long block of text that has no line breaks and split it into paragraphs that mostly make sense to human readability. On a different note, there is something else.
```

To this:

```
I am looking for a library or algorithm that can take my long block of text that has no line breaks and split it into paragraphs that mostly make sense to human readability.

On a different note, there is something else.
```

Comment: Do you want only line breaks on dots as in your sample, or something more elaborated ?

Comment: If you're just looking to add line breaks after punctuation, something like `gsub(/([.?!] )/, "\\1\n")` should do it (though it will also break at abbreviations; left as an excercise).

Answer (score 0):

If you just want line breaks at dots, you can use (for js) :

```
mybigline.split(". ").join("\n\n");
```

If you also want to format each line up to maxlen charts, breaking at words, you can also break each paragraph at a word boundary, something like :

```
var maxlen = 20;
var line = "vlaze lkdf lskdjf sldfsldfk sldkjf sldsd qsdkj qlskdj qlsdkj qlsdkj qlsdkj qlsdkj sldkfjsldfj fkj sldkfj s. qsldkjqsdlj. skdjhqksdjhqskjdq sd.";

// split into lines at dots
var par = line.split(". ");
var out = []
for (i in par) {
  // each line into words
  var pline = par[i].split(" ");
  var curline = "";
  for (j in pline) {
    // add words to output up to maxlength
    var curch = pline[j];
    if(curline.length + curch.length < maclent) {
      curline += curch + (pline.length==1?"":" ");
    } else {
      out.push(curline);
      curline = curch + (pline.length==1?"":" ");    
    }
  }
  out.push(curline);
  out.push("\n");
}
res = out.join("\n");
alert(res);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/37Lbj701/